# How to let ngForm know that the form it is nested in have been submitted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-ng-form

### What I know

In Angular 1.3 and above I have access to [`$submitted`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/type/form.FormController) that can tell me if the form in question have been submitted.
This works fine and dandy when working with a form in a way like this:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="register();" novalidate>
    <div>
        <input placeholder="First Name" name="name" type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" required />
        <span ng-show="myForm.$submitted && myForm.name.$error.required"> First Name is required</span>
    </div>
    <ng-form name="subForm">
        <div>
            <input placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" type="text" ng-model="user.Name" required />
            <span ng-show="myForm.$submitted && subForm.lastName.$error.required"> Last Name is required</span>
        </div>
    </ng-form>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

### The problem

But if I generate the ng-form dynamically, and therefore do not know the name of the form that the ng-form is nested in, I'm running into problems when I want to know if the parent have been submitted. I want this information so I can use it as a parameter for when to show a validation error message for the input in the nested ng-form.

Say I have a directive that i want to use as part of my form.

### Index file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="lastNameDirective.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="formExample">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate>
      <input placeholder="First Name" name="name" type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" required />
      <span ng-show="myForm.$submitted && myForm.name.$error.required"> First Name is required</span><br />
      <last-Name></last-Name>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Directive

```
angular.module('formExample', [])
  .directive('lastName', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'my-template.html'
    };
  });
```

### Template

```
<ng-form name="subForm">
    <input placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" type="text" ng-model="user.Name" required />
    <span ng-show="subForm.$submitted && subForm.lastName.$error.required"> Last Name is required</span>
</ng-form>
```

How do I get around this situation? Is there any way to either dynamically get the name of the form my ng-form is nested in, or can I somehow listen for a submit on my parent form?

[A little plunker to play around with](http://plnkr.co/edit/wEYCmYZgJau485KoqdBp?p=preview)

## What I have looked at

I have tried looking at [RealCrowds Angular-Utilities](https://github.com/realcrowd/angularjs-utilities), and is using this in my current project (as I have been using Angular 1.2 up till now), but it doesn't seem like they can handle the scenario either. (Even though [there have been some talk about it](http://code.realcrowd.com/on-the-bleeding-edge-advanced-angularjs-form-validation/#comment-1151628626))

Comment: All your links point to the same location; looks like one of them should be https://github.com/realcrowd/angularjs-utilities

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I will update that ASAP, don't know what happend

Comment: your question isn't clear;  You suggest that you can't know the name of the form you are nested in because you are generating the form dynamically, but you don't provide any demonstration or code showing this dynamic generation.

Comment: Can you might explain why you use ng-form? How many subforms are you expected to be dynamically generated and what is the connection to each other and how is your complete form going to look like?

Comment: Ok, I can do that :)
Will update the question with some generic way of showing how & why I would generate the ng-form dynamically and where the ng-form have no idea of the name of the form it is placed in

Comment: @Claies how would you feel about that update? Better?

Comment: @ABr does the update of my question explain why I would want to do that, and how many I potentionally could get?

Comment: this is most likely related to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5858.  It's not exactly the same thing as what you want to do, but it uses the same element structure, and has some ideas and workarounds for accessing the various elements in the form tree.

Comment: @Claies sorry, but I'm having a hard time not reading that thread as if they are trying the opposite?
As I see it, they wan't to isolate the nested form for the parent, I however, want to let the nested form know that the parent have received a submit

Comment: I now see that I might now have been all that clear about that point, that I want to know about the submission of the parent. I have now updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require the parents formController within the directive, and expose it.

```
....directive('lastName', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
    require:'^form',
    link:link
  };

  function link(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
    scope.parentForm = formCtrl;
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/pKonBjl57bjp4PaokARV

---

**Would suggest** exposing the parents formController through the controllerAs syntax - assuming the main form has a controller. Leaner markup and no need for the require example shown above

Comment: Awesome! Just as I intended it to be :D

Answer (score 0):

Squazz!

I guess i have a solution for you:
as i saw on plunkr second span was hide all the time.
The mark is that your submit button is assigned to the main form, and when you check `$submit` on a `subForm` it was not submitted, because there is no `<submit>` for the `subForm`.
so as i understood you can check a main form all time. Your [fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/PPaqbhuMjzVRESgNw4UB?p=preview).

Hope i helped.

Comment: Sorry, not really what I was looking for. I have updated the question quite a lot, maybe that helps to show you what I'm after :)